# HttpResponse.Redirect Delay

Tags: c#, redirect, web, httpresponse

So ... I have a site redirect (`HttpResponse.Redirect`) that has to direct to a URL that takes a while to load (the site is just awful)

The issue is that until the site responds properly, my sites URL stays visible, making it appear that my site is what is slow :(

Does anyone know how I can have the browsers URL update while its loading the redirect?

P.S. This is for an internal facing site that is directing to another internal facing site, so URL manipulation is allowable despite the practice usually frowned upon.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of would be, by using an iFrame and load that particular slow loading page in that frame. Then your page with the iFrame will load fast and show the URL appropriately. You would even be able to show a loading icon or something.

However do take in account this isn't a pretty solution. You'd better figure out what is taking the page so long to load. And improve that.

For example, are you loading a lot of data from the DB? Then you might improve that by using paging.

Good luck.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions. Sadly an iFrame I cannot do as my service is a URL re-director; one URL that doesn't change that dynamically links to the source so that if the source changes all existing links need not change. Also allows for central logging of link usage.

The site that I am directing to is the main intranet and is slow as. I sadly am not in charge, nor develop, this site and have no ability to influence change. We have logged many bugs and requests to have it sorted to only be met with resistance and denial of the reality.

Thanks again for the suggestions though!

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you're out of luck. As it is out of your hands to actually do something about the causing element. An iFrame indeed isn't a possible solution in your case I see now. And changing the browser not really an option :). Since changing the browser URL whilst it's loading would involve changing the browser and even if you would be able to do it on one browser you would still need to implement this for every possible browser (also taking into account tablets and phones).

Comment: That's what I thought, and somewhat feared. One of my colleagues believed it was possible, but frowned upon; I wasn't so sure.

Thank you again for your responses :)